# SQL EXISTS condition in Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, doctrine-query

I'd like to express the following sql query in Symfony 1.4 using Doctrine's Query Builder :

```
select `user_agent`
from ticket
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
          FROM log
          WHERE ticket.id = log.ticket_id AND log.task_id = 1)
```

How I can express the "where exist....." condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use exists statement in where clause as other conditions. In your case it would look something like:

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable('ticket')->createQuery('t')
    ->select('user_agent')
    ->addWhere('exists(select * from log l where l.ticket_id = t.id AND l.task_id = 1')
    ->fetchArray();
```